# Google Drive API v3 C# SDK Invalid Credentials

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, credentials

I'm trying to upload a file in Google Drive using v3 API, but i don't understand how to get access.

I have aleady the token obtained by OAuth2 (I make a request for grant access to Google Drive of user and obtain tokens)

There is my code, but I don't understand how put the token for the authentication.

```
//creazione servizio
var DriveService = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService();

//creazione del file
Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
body.Name = nome;
body.MimeType = mimeType;

//upload del file
Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request = DriveService.Files.Create(body,file,mimeType);
request.OauthToken = token;
request.Fields = "id";
request.Upload();

Response.Write(request.Upload().Exception.Message);

var returnFile = request.ResponseBody;

if (returnFile != null)
{
    esito.urlFile = returnFile.Id;
    esito.esito = true;
}
```

Thanks in advance to everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid Credentials, which you have indicated in your SO post title, is usually encountered if the access token you're using is either expired or invalid as stated in [Handling API Errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#errors_and_suggested_actions).

Suggested action for such error is to refresh the access token using the long-lived refresh token. If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow, as described in [Authorizing Your App with Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#AboutAuthorization).

I find it helpful and you will understand better about Authentication and Upload Files if you go through these tutorials:

1. [Google Drive Authentication C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-authentication-c/)
2. [Google Drive API with C# .net – Upload](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/)

Hope those tutorials help. :)

Comment: Thank you Teyam, you helped me very great! I wasn't sure about where specify the token, but now i'm sure that this line "request.OauthToken = token;" is right.
The problem was the token as you indicated. There was a bug in the method that retrieve the refreshed token. 
My posted code is working good.
Thank you!!